Convert AD date to DateTime on angular
I'm getting the attribute lastlogon from my Active directory in my angular website like this:
133523714173245792.
I want to convert this to readable date time
I have tried the date pipe like this:
 <span>{{ computer?.lastlogon | date}}</span>

and
<span>{{ computer?.lastlogon | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</span>

adn always it throws the same error:
ERROR Error: NG02100: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "133523714173245792" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'
I tried to convert manually on several websites but always it returns telling it's invalid format.
The date is: 133523714173245792

{{ +computer?.lastlogon | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}, convert to number adding a "+"

Thanks for reply but i tried it and i get NaN, finally i found the result and it's a mathmatic equation: (value/10000000)-11644473600)*1000

Finally the solution is (value/10000000)-11644473600)*1000.
I dit a pipe which does this operation ans return a unix based miliseconds and then used the angular data pipe.
my own pipe:
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'adTimeConvert',
  standalone: true
})
export class AdTimeConvertPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: number, ...args: unknown[]): number {
    return ((value/10000000)-11644473600)*1000;
  }

}

and then use it in teh template like this:
<span>
{{computer?.lastlogon | adTimeConvert | date : "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"}}
</span>

